# Paste view code here * in drupal 7.15

Tags: drupal

*I am creating a site similar with stackoverflow Can anybody help me out for this problem .
I have created my custom content type along with the views but cant know what should i write in this field in "
You are here
Home » Administration » Structure » Views" of the drupal site.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here for instructions on how to build stack overflow in Drupal:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24814

It also looks like you could use a views tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MSr3UnRkPI

Good luck!